# How do I create both V1 and V2 version of Azure Function Apps using VSCode on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have both .net core 2.0 and .net 4.7.2 installed.

I have installed Azure Function Apps Extension in VScode and a have verified that azure-functions-core-tools v2 is also installed.

I am able to create and debug V2 Function Apps using .netcore with no problems.

My question is how do I also install the tooling for V1 Function Apps side by side using VSCode and be able to debug as well?

thanks

Comment: Hi, have you tried my solution? Is it work?

Comment: Hi
Sort of !- I understand with your approach the tools are installed locally instead of globally and hence I can then do this in separate VScode windows.

following your approach for v2 works if all I want to do is run the function - when I attempt to debug I am prompted to install the the tools again globally.

For v1 functions when I try to run I get an Unauthorized exception and similarly when I try to debug it tries to install the tools again globally - also it also says I need the x64 bit version of the tools which the instruction is to overwrite the version npm installs.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

**1, Delete the global `azure-functions-core-tools` version.**

Go to the cmd, use the command below:

```
npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools
```

**2, Then go to the VS Code, create a empty folder.**

Press F1, click [image], then click the language.[image]

Now you can see multiple version of function that you can choose:

[image]

Click what you want.

**3, Create a folder named `node_modules` under your function app folder.**

[image]

**4, Click F1 to open the cmd terminal.**

[image]

If you choose v2 just now, please use this command:

`npm install azure-functions-core-tools@2`

[image]

Now, It has been create successfully.

**5, How to run test your azure function:**

Use this command on local:

```
node_modules\.bin\func host start
```

**How to create function v1 is similar.**

Answer (score 0):

just run below command
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true